# TextField not showing keyboard

Tags: xcode, ios5

When I click the textfield, the keyboard doesn't show up.  I'm pushing the nib with pushViewController in another view.

When I tried loading the nib with the non-working textfield as the default view for the app, it works fine.  It just isn't working when I load it from another view.

Here is the code that I load it with:

```
MessageComposeViewController *nextLevelListVC = [[MessageComposeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessageComposeViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextLevelListVC animated:YES];
[nextLevelListVC release];
```

Comment: It appears that your view has something over it, try calling: [myTextField becomeFirstResonder]; on the viewWillAppear: method. And if the keyboard should show up.

Comment: No luck.  It just made the textfield active once the view loaded, but still no keyboard.  I can click the textfield which shows a blinking cursor, but nothing else happens.

Comment: Well then the problem is related to your view hierarchy. There probably is something over the Keyboard another view or something, because your UITextField is certainly working if a blinking cursor appears. How are you creating your UITextField? code? nibs?

Comment: That's odd, I don't see what else could be thrown over the view.  I'm creating the TextField with the interface designer.

Comment: Have you tried creating it in code? Or maybe re-doing the IB file? I can't imagine a reason why the keyboard wouldn't show up if a blinking cursor appears.

Comment: Same issue here, did you solve it?

Comment: Veeru, haven't solved it yet.  El Developer, I've tried adding the textbox with code as well as re-doing the IB file.  I'm confident it's not an issue with the IB file because when I try adding the view as the default view in the app the textfields work fine.  If I find a solution I'll be sure to post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting my professor he pointed out what a possible solution was, after implementing what he suggested it fixed my issue.  Posting an explanation to help people who run into this in the future.

On my part it was a stupid mistake.  It had to do with me calling presentModalViewController earlier in my app.  I was using it in a way that it should not be used.  I was using it to direct flow from my login page. Here is a basic layout of the flow I had:

```
->delegate loads login view
'on successful login'
   ->presentModalViewController:dashboard
      'click messages'
      ->pushViewController
          'click create message'
          ->pushViewController (in the view pushed here, the keyboard wasn't working)
```

I re-wrote the navigation system to work with a flow similar to the one below:

```
->delegate loads dashboard 'if not logged in, load login'    
->presentModalViewController:login
          'click login'(validation would go here, etc)
->dismissModalViewController 'if logged in, go about normal activities' 'click message'
->pushViewController:messageView
    'click create message'
          ->pushViewController (keyboard working now)
```

When you present a modal view controller, you have to finish with it and dismiss it before presenting or pushing anymore views into your navigation view.

Hopefully this explanation is good enough to give people an understanding of what my problem was and how I solved it.